# Which packages is proper for dependence modeling using copula in Python?

Tags: python, openturns, copula

I'm facing a stochastic model which needs the copula tool to formulate the dependence within several random variables. For the unknown dependence structure, it would be better if as more the copula families as possible are supported, such as **Archimedean copulas**, **Elliptic copulas**, **Extreme Value copulas** and **Vine copulas**. Moreover, some dependence measures like **Kendall's tau**, **Spearman's rho** and **tail dependence** are expected to contain in the Python package. And another fundamental functions like PDF, CDF, conditional PDF are also well implemented. The efficient implemementation of the package is also expected.

I have tried the following packages:

- `openturns`
- `statsmodels`
- `copulas`
- `pycop`
- `pyvinecopulib`

and the `UQLab` in MATLAB, but no one can support all the requirements I listed above. `openturns` is the almost best answer but it doesn't support the rotated **Archimedean copulas** and **Vine copulas** and its conditional PDF is somewhat strange. For `pyvinecopulib`, it seems that the marginal distributions are not supported. `pycop` only support the survial copula of **Archimedean copulas** though it's called the rotated **Archimedean copulas**. `copulas` support calculating copula's parameter $\theta$ by Kendall's $\tau$ but it doesn't contain complex copula. `UQLab` doesn't have `PDF` function.

Comment: `pyvinecopulib` is a perfect package.

Comment: What exactly is "strange" in the conditional PDF from your point of view? I may agree on some points, and this is why I implemented a ConditionalDistribution shown at: https://github.com/mbaudin47/otbenchmark/blob/master/examples/ConditionalDistribution_Demo.ipynb

Comment: And the code is here: https://github.com/mbaudin47/otbenchmark/blob/master/otbenchmark/ConditionalDistribution.py